# What is the purpose of metamask if it does not support token purchases and I still need to use a token management service?

Tags: ether, tokens, metamask

My question is about the purpose of metamask if it does not support token purchases and I still need to use a token management service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metamask is a Chrome plugin that allows anyone to interact with the Ethereum blockchain with having to run a full node. 
Just install it and you can start using supported dapps.

That being said. Metamask **is** used to buy tokens. You can use Metamask to interact with ICO smart contracts and it is used to trade Erc20 tokens, for example over EtherDelta.

Comment: so if I bought or participated in an ICO those tokens i bought with ETH should appear on my metamask account?

Comment: Yes, you have to go to the tokens tab and add the contract address of the tokens you bought

Comment: I tried buying on EtherDelta and my order could not be fullfilled because of "transaction underpriced" what does that mean? and was my gas price or gas limit to small?

Comment: Try increasing gas price

Comment: yeah thats what I did, funny thing was that I got the same error message/ failed message, at that point my gas price was causing a greater tx fee than what I was getting in ETH. It was just a testing experience, since that was my first time interacting and buying with metamask transfering to EtherDelta

Comment: Yeah, mi point is that it is not a problem of Matamask

Comment: I got your point, thank you, one last question, is giving someone my txHash a security threat? is it a no no? or is it like a transaction number where it is not that big of a security problem, unless your credit card number is completely shown?

Comment: The transaction hash is publicly available. If you search your address on etherscan you can see all transactions and the details.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! you are a gentlman and a scholar of the highest magnitude. no really thank you very much. I hope to continue learning and maybe I can confide in your knowledge and ask future questions